# Join results and sum of likes in a different table

Tags: mysql

I have two databases, articles and article-likes.
I need the query to select everything from the `article` and add a row which is the sum of likes (we have -1 for dislike and +1 for like) from the table `article-likes` by searching for their ID.

Articles table:
[image: Articles]
 Article-Likes table:
[image: Article-likes]

For this instance, the article with ID `Lorem-Ipsum` should have 2 likes. On the other hand, `Sit-Amet` should have 1 like (1 + -1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to sum all likes of each article.

```
SELECT author,
       name,
       text,
       id,
       (SELECT SUM(value)
        FROM Articles-Likes
        WHERE articles_id = Articles.ID) as Likes  
from   Articles
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the details (IP address, etc) of each Like?  If not, avoid that because of how bulky it is and how slow the SUM will be if someone gets as many [dis]likes as Trump.

Instead, have a 2-column table with article_id and the current tally.  To modify, `UPDATE LikeCounts SET ct = ct + (or minus) 1 WHERE article_id = ?`  In this case the select becomes:

```
SELECT ...,
       LikeCounts.ct AS "Net Likes"
    FROM Articles
    JOIN LikeCounts USING(article_id)
```

If you like, you could have two counters - one for likes, one for dislikes.  This would give you the info on how many people bothered to vote.